# How to wrap & with "" to escape ampersand

Tags: powershell

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9536) it is mentioned :

```
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
```

How do we do this to this string?  If we wrap it with "&" then it breaks the string into two.

```
$saskey = "ssdsdsdsd&dsdsdwwwe1212" #auto-generated
```

This does not make sense:

```
$sasKey = $sasKey.replace("&",""&"")
```

"Unexpected token '&' in expression or statement error" is what we get

I want to pass this to a function in Azure automation and because of the ampersand I only get the first part "ssdsdsdsd". This is the automation runbook.

```
function MyFunc {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$sasKey
    )


    cd c:\upload
    $Env:AZCOPY_AUTO_LOGIN_TYPE = "MSI"
    
    $sourcePath = "c:\upload"
    $destPath="https://server.blob.core.windows.net/vmuploads" + $sasKey
    azcopy login --identity
    azcopy copy  $sourcePath $destPath --recursive
    
    #just to view the content in the VM
    $coreSitePath = "c:\upload\log.txt"
    $destPath | Out-File -FilePath $coreSitePath -Force 

}
...
...

    $context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storageRg -Name $storageAccountName).context
    $sasKey = New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Context $context -Service Blob -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup"

    $ScriptToRun = Get-Content Function:\MyFunc
    Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1

    # Run Func in VM
    $params = @{"sasKey" = $sasKey}
    
    $result=Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $VMResourceGroupName -VMName $VMname -ScriptPath "ScriptToRun.ps1" -Parameter  $params  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' # -Parameter $params
```

Comment: No, it won't break the string. Please [edit] the question and show with more details how the string is being broken.

Comment: How would you do it?  "wrap an ampersand" , could you show a line of code?

Comment: So, did you try the workaround as mentioned in the issue? *This can be circumvented by wrapping the SAS token with double quotes inside the string literal:* `$saskey = '"ssdsdsdsd&dsdsdwwwe1212"'`

Comment: you mean `$saskey = "$saskey"` ? $saskey is autogenerated.

Comment: Quote: *so that the CLI command looks like this:* `--sas-token "ssdsdsdsd&dsdsdwwwe1212"`

Comment: Added the real code. and the link does not.

Comment: Try: `$params = @{ sasKey = """$sasKey""" }` (triple double quotes at the start and end).